# How much can one say about homology of a sphere bundle using spectrual sequence?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a sphere bundle $\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow X\rightarrow B$.Then using Serre spectural sequence, most of the second page is 0 except for the first and the $n$th line, and if we pass to the final page, we will get a map $d_k:H_k(B)\rightarrow H_{k+n+1}(B)$,and $H_k(X)\cong Ker d_k \oplus Coker d_{k-1}$. What can we say about $d_k$?
In particular, if we let base space $B=\mathbb{S}^k$ for some k,then it seems that the homology of total space is trivial except for 4 dimensions, which is also easy to deal since they seems to be $\mathbb{Z}$ except for the case $k=n+1$. I searched for some realted articles but none states spectural sequnce. Is there any refrences about that?

Comment: The keyword is *Gysin Sequence*. Your own observations take you most of the way to constructing it.

Comment: don't you need the sphere bundle to be fibre-oriented to get an integral Gysin sequence, otherwise you only get one with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients? (if $B=S^k$ for $k >1$ then it will be orientable automatically)

Comment: in the case that the sphere bundle is non-orientable then $\pi_1(B)$ will have a non-trivial action on the cohomology of the fibres, so the spectral sequence is more subtle

Comment: @Tyrone are you talking about the cohomological case,where $d_k$ can be expalined as cup product with the euler class? So is there any similar thing related with that?

Comment: See Spanier *Algebraic Topology* Theorem 11, pg. 260 for a statement and proof of the Gysin Sequence. For a generalised statement with proof by means of the LSSS, see Theorem 3 pg. 483.

Comment: @Tyone I see.Thanks!

Comment: @William In some sense the trvial action condition is automatically satisfied when I consider the bundle, i.e. I omit some technical details in order to focus on some "big picture". Actually the case of sphere bundles over spheres is what I take care the most,so  it seems that the total space is simply-connected by the exact sequence of fibre bundle.